# Adding row in Excel and incrementing an account number

Tags: excel, vba

I am taking over a mailing list from an outside vendor. We will be using Excel 2010. There is a unique account number column.

I need a macro to be able to determine when a new row is being added as opposed to existing row being modified and then how to the get max(account number) and add 1 to it to keep the new account number unique.

Answer (score 0):

You could track the changes made to your sheet. If a changed cell is found non-blank on a row that has nothing in the Account Number column, then the new account number is calculated and filled in:

Put this code in the worksheet's VBA module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim record As Range
    Dim maxAccountNo As Long

    For Each record In Target.Rows
        If Cells(record.row, 1) = "" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(record.EntireRow) > 0 Then
            If Not maxAccountNo Then
                maxAccountNo = 1 + WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("$A:$A"))
            End If
            Cells(record.row, 1) = maxAccountNo
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This will also cover cases where you copy/paste several rows that have no account number filled in.

Note that this code assumes the account number is in column A, excluding the first row. Adapt this reference in the code, if necessary:

```
$A2:$A100000
```

.. and also the column number in:

```
Cells(record.row, 1)
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave a comment?